# Is there a C# equivalent to Java CompletionService to react to completed threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

There are lots of examples of how to wait for all 'worker' jobs to finish, but what about reacting as each worker completes in the same way as Java's CompletionService?

I've hacked together something that works, but this seems fragile:

```
int completedWorkers = 0;
while (completedWorkers < workerCount)
{
     int eventId = WaitHandle.WaitAny(eventArray);
     events[eventId].Reset();
     completedWorkers++;
     Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} has completed. {1} have now completed.", eventId, completedWorkers);
}
Console.WriteLine("All threads have finished");
```

This relies on an array of ManualResetEvent instances ('eventArray' in my example), similar to that shown in the Microsoft example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx (however their code uses WaitAll() to wait for all workers to finish, not reacting as each worker finishes).

**Edit:**

I've accepted Douglas's answer using the TPL, but for reference, Delegates give us this functionality out of the box:

```
IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(
                new AsyncCallback(CallbackMethod),
                "The call executed on thread {0}, with return value \"{1}\".");

...

void CallbackMethod(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
    // 'react' to async delegates completing
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the Task Parallel Library, you could attach a continuation to each of your tasks.

```
int completedWorkers = 0;
var continuations = tasks.Select((task, index) => task.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
{
    lock (tasks)   // only required if you want to avoid races between incrementing and writing
    {
        int _index = index;   // avoid closures issue
        completedWorkers++;   // if lock is removed, replace with: Interlocked.Increment(ref completedWorkers);
        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} has completed. {1} have now completed.", _index, completedWorkers);
    }
}));
Task.WaitAll(continuations.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("All threads have finished");
```

Comment: Very elegant - it'll be interesting to see if there are any solutions that can be used before .NET 4.5.

Comment: @Forge_7: This works on .NET 4.0 too. For earlier versions, I would either use a technique similar to yours, or add an event to be called from within the tasks.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I changed to 4.5 to use the Task.Run method to setup the tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an example that requires .NET 4.5 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx

```
// ***Add a loop to process the tasks one at a time until none remain. 
while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
{
     // Identify the first task that completes.
     Task<int> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);

     // ***Remove the selected task from the list so that you don't 
     // process it more than once.
     downloadTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);

     // Await the completed task. 
     int length = await firstFinishedTask;
     resultsTextBox.Text += String.Format("\r\nLength of the download:  {0}", length);
}
```

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer, as it matches the original desired behavior whereas the other does not. Your original question includes two reasonable alternatives for pre-4.5 code.